# How can I install a specific version of an R package on a spark cluster on DataBricks?

Tags: r, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I am trying to install a specific version of an R package on one of our clusters.
I can install any package I want without specifying the version, but the problem is that I don't know how to install a specific version of a package.

[image]

So, here, I have a couple of R packages installed, but I don't know how to install "latticeExtra_0.6-28".

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

I have tried different variations of the package name, but couldn't solve it.
Examples of failed trials are:
latticExtra_0.6.28
latticeExtra===0.6.28
latticeExtra_0_6_28
latticeExtra==0.6.28
latticeExtra==0.6-28

Answer (score 1):

By default R installs the latest version of the package. If you need to install specific version you need to use `devtools::install_version()` function, or install from specific source performing that from the [notebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/notebooks-r-libraries). If you want to install it on the cluster level, then you can use the older snapshots of CRAN specified as a source repository - see this [Databricks knowledge base article](https://kb.databricks.com/r/pin-r-packages) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alex's answer, I also found the following article super useful.

https://github.com/marygracemoesta/R-User-Guide/blob/master/Developing_on_Databricks/package_management.md

Comment: Providing an example of code you adapted using these resources would help the next person